# How to display React app in IE? When it works fine in all other browsers localhost and production?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cross-browser

I had a client complain to me that the production build of my React Application (no cli uses custom webpack configuration) is displaying fine in all browsers except for IE. It works in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge but it displays a blank page on IE. I opened up my IE browser and looked to see if it threw any errors any no errors are present in the console.

I think the problem has to do with the way my webpack configuration is set up. Here it is:

1. I already installed Isomorphic fetch and es6 promise dependency
   packages and using them for all my fetch requests. (I'm using async
   await for my promises)
2. I tried adding targets to my custom webpack
   configuration to no success either.

```
const path = require("path");
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require("browser-sync-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", __dirname + "/src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          query: {
            presets: [
              [
                "env",
                {
                  targets: {
                    browsers: ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "react",
              "stage-0"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" },
          { loader: "sass-loader" }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Disable code splitting as it's creating many duplicate bundle profiles
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3312,
      files: [
        "./public/*.html",
        "./public/assets/scss/*.scss",
        "./public/assets/variables/*.scss",
        "./public/assets/mixins/*.scss",
        "./public/assets/reset/*.scss"
      ],
      proxy: "http://localhost:3000/"
    })
  ]
};
```

This is my index.js file rendering the app

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "./routes";

ReactDOM.render(<div>{routes}</div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I expect to be able to see my React app in both localhost and production build for IE instead of not seeing anything for IE.

Comment: I've had to use other polyfills, like a custom polyfill.js entry file (https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/351) which did things like import/require('core-js') and everything else.

You should open up IE console and see where it's hanging/crashing. You could even have a dependency that wasn't correctly compiled into ES5 -- so console would say error at some line in the bundle and if you scroll up, you should see a commented banner labeling the source file.

Comment: Okay I know what my issue is. I looked into the libary that was throwing the error and in the documentation it says they don't have compatibility support for I.E yet but they do for all the other browsers so thats why it's not working. I'll have to downgrade the version of the library I'm using (which is the newest version) in order to make it compatible and fix this issue.